# Conversion operator with default template argument

Tags: c++, templates, conversion-operator

I was wondering what's wrong with the [following code](https://ideone.com/yWVtgR):

```
template<typename T, typename U = T> 
    operator U() 
    {
        return U();
    }
```

It fails with `error: no matching function for call to 'Test1::Test1(Test&)'`, whereas the conversion on the [following code](https://ideone.com/XcRkTn) succeeds:

```
template<typename T> 
    operator T() 
    {
        return T();
    }
```

---

The complete code:

https://ideone.com/yWVtgR

```
class Test
{
    public:
        template<typename T, typename U = T> 
        operator U() 
        {
            return U();
        }
};
class Test1{};

int main() {
    Test t;
    Test1 t1 = (Test1)t;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/XcRkTn

```
class Test
{
    public:
        template<typename T> 
        operator T() 
        {
            return T();
        }
};
class Test1{};

int main() {
    Test t;
    Test1 t1 = (Test1)t;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including classes and how you use them to get the error. And by showing us, I mean *put the code in the question*, links can go stale and make your question worthless.

Comment: You already have it. Did you click the links?

Comment: Did you not see "put your code in the question" - as in "not in a link"?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well I *did* edit my comment, it wasn't originally there. :)

Comment: Added the example inline in the question, in a addition to links to ideone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it too hard for the compiler with this

```
template<typename T, typename U = T> 
operator U() 
{
    return U();
}
```

The code says "U is the same type as T". And the compiler asks "And what is T?". `T` isn't used anywhere in your code, so the compiler cannot deduce it.

`typename U = T` only works one way, to define `U` when `T` is known.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I use T in my code. Change the operator return value to `return T();` for example.

Comment: That's still not enough for the compiler to figure out `T`. Your code says that `U` is the same as `T`. Oddly enough that doesn't imply that `T` is the same as `U`.  :-)   The compiler must know `T` first.